# What is the difference in cors configuration in spring: `CorsWebFilte`r vs `WebFluxConfigurerComposite.addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)`?

Tags: spring, cors, spring-webflux

In my application with WebFlux functional endpoints this cors configuration didn't work:

```
@Bean
WebFluxConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebFluxConfigurerComposite() {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*");
        }
    };
}
```

with message:

> Failed to handle request [OPTIONS http://localhost:30300/create]: Response status 404 with reason "No matching handler"

but this one works:

```
@Bean
CorsWebFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return new CorsWebFilter(source);
}
```

Why? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebFluxConfigurer` configuration infrastructure applies to the annotation model and the functional model in Spring WebFlux.

In this case, the CORS configuration is applied to the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean which is created by `WebFluxConfigurationSupport`.

On the other hand, it is also applied to the `RouterFunctionMapping` which supports the functional model. But that implementation is first checking that a handler is matching the incoming request, before optionally handling it as a CORS request if necessary (for example, a preflight request).

One could argue that this is on purpose, to make the `RouterFunction` model explicit and not hide anything from developers. The `CorsWebFilter` is a more global mechanism, probably more suited to the functional model anyway, but you could still consider that as a enhancement request and create a new issue on https://jira.spring.io (please do!).